# Picking a parser generator for building an interpreter for a custom language using C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, compiler-construction, programming-languages, interpreter

This is the first time I go into actually trying to implement a Domain Specific Language.

I know the basics of language grammars and Abstract Syntax Trees, however I didn't get my hands dirty in implementing them before.

I want to build a small language, simple variables/arrays and conditional statements. I want to interpret and execute the user entered code via an interpreter I build by C#. Something pretty similar in spirit to PHP tho way simpler.

I searched and I became confused.

Best parser generators I found which had good C# supports were Gold and Irony. I also found ANTLR but I saw too many people complaining about problems with C# suppots. Also, the three of those seem to lack good documentation.

My main fear is to begin working with one of them and then discovering its not usable for the task, either because of lack of good C# support, or good documentation or something else. I want something that I can begin working with "confidently" to get myself kickstarted in the project.

Could anyone help me to pick something that does the job well and guaranteed to work well with C# ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use ANTLR. I wrote my own compiler (for MSIL) using it.
ANTLR has C# support and i did not found any problems with it.

U can also look at [my source code](http://code.google.com/p/wlcompiler/) (i can not be working sample, but it has ANTLT .g file) for sample.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try [TinyPG](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28294/a-Tiny-Parser-Generator-v1-2). It compiles to C#, and you can provide C# directly in the grammar.